# How to Print the Gridlines in Libreoffice Writer?

Tags: printing, libreoffice

I'm aware of the fix for this issue in LibreOffice Calc (Go to format -> page -> sheet -> print grid lines), but no matter what I do, I can't seem to be able to print the grid lines for a table in Writer. Also, this fix apparently doesn't work, because there isn't a sheet option in Writer. Anyone know of a fix for this?

Comment: I assume you have selected the appropriate gridline arrangement under **Table** --> **Properties** --> **Borders**?

Comment: @steeldriver Actually, I didn't even think to use that despite it being right on the top of the menu bar. I don't know why I have to do that for each table though, kind of a pain. Maybe I can use `Ctrl + A` with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The appearance of table gridlines is actually provided by the **borders** of the individual cells.

The dialog for **Table** --> **Insert table...** should include a **Border** checkbox:

[image: LO Insert table]

In a clean default installation of LibreOffice 5, this box seems to be checked by default - if yours isn't, you can change the default setting by going to **Tools** --> **Options** --> **Libreoffice Writer** --> **Table** and modify the **New Table Defaults** settings:

[image: LO New Table Defaults]

To add printable gridlines to an existing table, go to **Table** --> **Properties** --> **Borders** :

[image: LO Table properties]